# Group by multiple columns and add them

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table something like below

| level1 | level2 | level3 | key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | k1 |
| A | B | C | K2 |
| A | B | D | k2 |
| A | B | E | k3 |
| A | F | G | k4 |
| A | F | null | k5 |
| A | null | null | k6 |
| A | B | null | k7 |
| A | B | null | k8 |

I am expecting to carry hierarchy information to child count like below

```
A-->1
A-->B -->2+1(a)=3
A-->B--->C-->1+2+2( 2 entries for ABC)=5
A--B-->D-->1+2+1=4
A--B-->E-->1-->1+2+1=4
A--F-->1+1=2
A--F-->G-->1+1+1=3
```

My tried the query below does not give the right result

```
select CONCAT(ifnull(level1, ''), ' > ', ifnull(level2, ''), ' > ', ifnull(level3, '')) as 'foo',COUNT(*) as 'count' from table t t.level1, t.level2, t.level3;
```

How can I apply the aggregate function and fetch the right result.

Comment: `FROM` is followed by the table name, not column names. You should get a syntax error from that query.

Comment: Did you mean to have `GROUP BY` before the list of columns? I suspect what you're looking for is `GROUP BY columns list WITH ROLLUP`. But I don't see how you're getting the results you show -- shouldn't the count of `A` be `9`, not `1`?

Comment: Lets say grand parent has 1 mango parent has 2 and child has 3 so gp=1  ,p=3 and c=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
with concat_levels as 
(
  select concat_ws('>', level1, level2) lvl_1_2, 
         concat_ws('>', level1, level2, level3) lvl_1_2_3, count(*) cn
  from table_name
  group by 1, 2
)
select t1.lvl_1_2_3 as levels, 
       t1.cn + coalesce(sum(t2.cn), 0) as res
from concat_levels t1 left join concat_levels t2
on t1.lvl_1_2_3 like (concat(t2.lvl_1_2, '%')) and 
   length(t1.lvl_1_2_3) > length(t2.lvl_1_2_3)
group by t1.lvl_1_2_3, t1.cn
order by t1.lvl_1_2_3
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2qO0EquL)

Comment: Thanks have issue running this in mysql  5.7

Comment: @javascriptlearner, for mysql 5.7 you can use sub query instead of the cte, see this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/ReP6GbUb

Answer (score 1):

This query gave me desired result:

```
with g as (
  select level1 l1, level2 l2, level3 l3, count(1) cnt 
  from mytable group by level1, level2, level3)
select concat(g3.l1, 
              case when g3.l2 is null then '' else concat('>', g3.l2) end, 
              case when g3.l3 is null then '' else concat('>', g3.l3) end) path,
          case when g3.l3 is null then g3.cnt
               else g1.cnt +g2.cnt + g3.cnt end cnt
from g g3
left join g g1 on g1.l2 is null and g3.l3 is not null and g3.l1 = g1.l1
left join g g2 on g2.l2 is not null and g2.l3 is null and g3.l3 is not null 
      and g3.l1 = g2.l1 and g3.l2 = g2.l2
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_UtRORZe)

except for AFG which should be 3? (A once + AF once + AFG once).

Query groups values at first, then self joins all occurences `g3` with two occurences `g2` and one occurence `g1` and presents as requested.

Comment: yes afg should be 3 and af 1

Comment: AB should be equal to 3

Comment: If you want to include parents also for middle rows then minor change in join is needed: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bc_WyeG-). I go to sleep :)

Comment: Thanks I am running into issue running this in mysql 5.7